# How to avoid cross mark symbol when there is no source in image tag (src=" " )

Tags: javascript, html

I have two images, one with source `src=" www.png"` another with no source `src=""`. The image with no source is showing a symbol (I don't know symbol), how can I avoid this?

Comment: Why do you want an img element with no src? If the idea is to have an "empty" img on the page that later gets a `src` added you could just toggle the display via `visibility:hidden` and `visibility:visible`.

Comment: The symbol is the "This image could not be found" symbol. If you don't want it, don't put nonsense in your src attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Use a transparent blank placeholder PNG, or better yet, don't add useless empty images to your document. If you need to programmatically set the `src` to a non-empty value later, you can append a new `<img>` element at that point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use transparent base64 encoded **GIF** image:

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAP///wAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to "fix" this.

You can either set a php function like this:

```
<?php
function printSrc( $path )
{
   $missingImage = 'missing_image.png';

   if( ! file_exists( $path ) )
   {
       $path = $missingImage;
   }

   echo $path;
}
?>

<?php $imagePath = 'image.png'; ?>
<img src="<?php printSrc( $imagePath ) ?>"/>
```

This would show your "missing image" image instead of just nothing when you don't have anything to display.

You could also do

```
 <img src="image.php?file=image.png"/>
```

And that image.php would have the same conditional and output an image with php.

There are also css hacks and tweaks others mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$image = "imageurl";
if(!file_exists($image){
echo ' <img alt="" />';
}else {
echo '<img src="' . $image . '"/>
```